# Google App Engine : Google App Engine spamming logs for connection refused to Redis, but it's working

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, redis, gcloud

I am working on deploying my NodeJS app on Google App Engine. App is working good, and I have created a redis instance, which is added as ENV parameter. It's working fine, but somehow Gooogle App Engine is spamming logs with connection by redis to localhost is refused. I am not even using redis on localhost, but I keep getting that error.

App.yaml config :

```
REDIS_HOST="10.0.0.11"
REDIS_PORT="6379"
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
```

Error log

```
 redis error { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
{
 insertId: "5f05bd7d000dc253c8201a6a"  
 
labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/staging-app-io/logs/stdout"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-07-08T12:35:10.150457785Z"  
 
resource: {…}  
 textPayload: "redis error { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379"  
 timestamp: "2020-07-08T12:35:09.901715Z"  
}
```

Any idea how I can inform GAE that I am using Redis defined above, and not localhost.

Complete app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard

# Update with Redis instance details
env_variables:
  REDISHOST: '10.0.0.11'
  REDISPORT: '6379'

# Update with Serverless VPC Access connector details
vpc_access_connector:
  name: 'projects/PROJNAME/locations/europe-west3/connectors/PROJNAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

When in production, you need to tell Redis the proper HOST, PORT, & PASSWORD.  It should be something like:

```
'REDIS_HOST'      : 'redis-12345.c1214.us-central1-1.gce.cloud.redislabs.com',
'REDIS_PORT'     : '15268',    # Default is 6379
'REDIS_PASSWORD'  : 'kadsfhasdf82348fh23',
```

Seems you haven't done that, so it is falling back to the defaults (127.0.0.1, 6379)

Comment: I have done this and added in app.yaml. it's posted in question. Or do i need to add this somewjere else?

Comment: We're going to need to see more code.  Show how you declared `env` vars in app.yaml.  Then show the code you used to connect using those vars.

Comment: I have added the complete app.yaml at bottom of main post.. Can u please check once. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Those are the default host and port for your local development.  To use in production, your app will not be able to access the IP address `10.0.0.11`.  That is a local, private IP.  In production, you need to use the URL and port that Redis has provided for you.  And you need to go to your Redis console and choose a password.  Your production credentials will look like something in my answer.